# Share circuit on localhost:9050 to the rest of the internal network

Tags: circuit

Might be a little off-topic but I don't know maybe it's more related to tor than networking.

Basically, I have the following scenario I want to accomplish:

home access point is 192.168.1.1,

computer-1 is 192.168.1.101,

computer-2 is 192.168.1.102

and phone-3 is 192.168.1.103

On computer-1 [192.168.1.101] I have a tor circuit established on its localhost:9050 (default torrc config etc..). I can use this circuit from computer-1 only.

What I'd like to do is make computer-1's localhost:9050 availalbe to computer-2 and phone-3 and all other devices on the network, so they can use it when they want. I want to accomplish this without changing anything in the way the circuit is opened on computer-1.

I am not good in networking, I guess I should maybe open the 9050 external port on computer-1? It runs debian and I tried with `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9050 -j ACCEPT` with no success.

Thanks to any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `SocksPort` option to specify not just the port, but IP+port explicitly. You will need to have two lines: one for localhost, one for 192.168.1.101 so it will be available for the localhost apps and for remote ones

Comment: Thank you, a little out-dated guidance but I managed in the end, here is what I went through:
`[notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
[warn] Skipping obsolete configuration option 'SocksListenAddress'
[warn] Option 'SocksListenAddress' used more than once; all but the last value will be ignored.
[warn] Skipping obsolete configuration option 'SocksListenAddress'
[notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
[notice] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050`
Looks like an old argument, I pondered around and found the very exact new vrsion of sockslistenaddress:
`SocksPort`

Comment: So adding these two lines: `SocksPort 127.0.0.1:9050
SocksPort 192.168.1.101:9050` (instead of sockslistenaddress) did the trick.

Comment: maybe update and clean out the answer now

Comment: SocksPort is working also, in the very same way - **be sure and double-check** for the lines for localhost and LAN **SEPARATELY**

Comment: ok so I am confused, what is the difference between adding `SocksPort 127.0.0.1:9050 SocksPort 192.168.1.101:9050` to torrc and editing `TorAddress 127.0.0.1 TorPort 9050` in torsocks.conf? And does the option `AllowInbound 1` in torsocks.conf have anything to do with this as well?

Comment: The **only** option you do need is SocksPort